# Reactjs problem with CSS variable in style prop

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Firstly, this is my code:

```
<div className="phone" style="--bg: var(--green)">
```

But the error is like:

> Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

so I change my code into

```html
<div className="phone" style={{--bg: var(--green)}}>
    <div className="name">So dien thoai</div>
</div>
<div className="fb" style={{--bg: var(--blue)}}>
    <div className="name">Facebook</div>
</div>
<div className="gg" style={{--bg: var(--red)}}>
    <div className="name">Google</div>
</div>
```

```css
:root{
  --red: #ee4d2d;
  --blue: #0288d1;
  --green: #6cc942;
}
.phone, .fb, .gg{
    display: flex;
    padding: 4px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: var(--bg);
    
    .name{
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

They told me i can't use `--bg` in `style={{ }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
style={{'--bg': 'var(--green)'}}
```

in JSX you must use `style` attribute as above.

The first (outer) `{}` is the JSX syntax and the inner `{}` is the actual javascript object representing the style properties/values.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<div style={{'--bg': 'var(--green)'}}/>, document.body)
```

```css
body{ --green: green }

div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: var(--bg); /* using the variable defined from JSX */
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

I suggest you next time to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20style%20prop%20expects%20a%20mapping%20from%20style%20properties%20to%20values&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIL944IL945&oq=The%20style%20prop%20expects%20a%20mapping%20from%20style%20properties%20to%20values&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39i362l8j69i64.275j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) the error instead of rushing to open a new question here, as there is a ton of information on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20style%20prop%20expects%20a%20mapping%20from%20style%20properties%20to%20values&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIL944IL945&oq=The%20style%20prop%20expects%20a%20mapping%20from%20style%20properties%20to%20values&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39i362l8j69i64.275j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I got it. Hao Wu was right, they needed inside "".

Answer (score -2):

```
example: style={{color: "var(--red)"}} not ";"
style={{ "--bg": "var(--red)", background: "var(--bg)" }}
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-keldysh-4dspr?file=/src/App.js
```

Comment: Putting all your text in a code block makes it really difficult to read. Can you please format it better?